# How to upload and retrieve images from a Storage using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

How to upload photos using NodeJS to free cloud storage rather than google cloud and how can I retrieve photos from that cloud or storage?

So far I had tried many of these to sort, google cloud needs a credit card, is there any easy way to upload and retrieve images using NodeJs. I am storing images on website memory

```
var filePath = `/folder/imagesfolder/${require.file}.png`;
var tempPath = require.file.path;
var targetPath = path.join(__dirname,`../../${filePath}`);

fs.rename(tempPath,targetPath,async error=>{
    if(error!=null){
        console.log(error);
        return respond.sendStatus(400);
    }

    request.session.user =await  User.findByIdAndUpdate(id,{photo:filePath},{new:true});
    respond.sendStatus(204);
})
```

I had searched many sites but I haven't found any website for storing and retrieving images using NodeJs.However, I am able to store it in my website memory. Can anyone suggest a better way? To store and retrieve images from and on internet storage using my website. Can I use MongoDB to store images?

Comment: `free cloud storage`  Well it's going to depend on what API services they give you.

Comment: not sure what do you need to use with, but I think Imgur will be a good fit for your use.

Comment: I would like to store profile pictures of my users and retrieve them using a free service using Node. Is there any possibility?

Comment: Check out Google's Firebase. It has free storage and database too https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference, https://firebase.google.com/pricing